# Replace a specific tag of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have this JS string:

```
"<div>
  <p id='foo'>foo text</p>
  <p id='bar'>bar text</p>
  <p id='sol'>sol text</p>
</div>"
```

**And I want to replace only the paragraph id 'bar' and return all the string with the new modifcation. How can I do this?** I know I can use a regex, however if I can avoid it, it would be better I think...

I have tried to convert the string to a DOM object like this:

```
var str = "<div><p id='foo'>foo text</p><p id='bar'>bar text</p><p id='sol'>sol text</p></div>"
```

and then,

```
var dom_str = $(str);
```

however I don't know how to select the bar id and return all the string.

The output I want to get is the following for this example:

```
var result = "<div><p id='foo'>foo text</p><p id='bar'>new text here</p><p id='sol'>sol text</p></div>"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should look a little in the jQuery documentation for DOM manipulation and selection methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the `jQuery object` (it's not a dom element) do `$obj.find('#bar').text('new text here')`

```
var str = "<div><p id='foo'>foo text</p><p id='bar'>bar text</p><p id='sol'>sol text</p></div>"
var $obj = $(str);
$obj.find('#bar').text('new text here')
```

**note:** it's better to save the parsing in a variable `$obj` because if you need more work on that object you don't have to parse it every time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = "<div><p id='foo'>foo text</p><p id='bar'>bar text</p><p id='sol'>sol text</p></div>",
    el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = str;
el.querySelector('#bar').textContent = "new text here";
var result = el.innerHTML;
```